# How to get the latest row from table using JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a join of 5 tables to get the tasks posted by each member having about 15 columns. But for sample code I have taken just two tables of them.

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    dbo.MemberMst.MemberID, dbo.MemberMst.fname, 
    dbo.TaskMst.TaskMstID, dbo.TaskMst.OnDate, dbo.TaskMst.Description
FROM   
    dbo.MemberMst 
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.TaskMst ON dbo.MemberMst.MemberID = dbo.TaskMst.MemberID
```

Output is:

```
MemberID fname  TaskMstID    OnDate                   Description
3    Ursula     NULL         NULL                      NULL
84   Opeyemi    30           2012-09-18 00:00:00.000     asd
85   test       21           2012-09-18 10:30:46.900     aaa
85   test       22           2012-09-18 10:31:04.967     eeee
85   test       23           2012-09-18 10:31:26.640     vvvv
```

Here in above query I get 3 rows for `MemberID=85` who posted 3 tasks but I need only one task from that member which is the latest. How to get the latest task posted by a member so that result would be:-

```
MemberID fname  TaskMstID OnDate                Description
3    Ursula     NULL      NULL                   NULL
84   Opeyemi    30        2012-09-18 00:00:00.000   asd
85   test       23        2012-09-18 10:31:26.640   vvvv
```

I mean to say just only one record for each `memberID` having tasks?

Help appreciated..!

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can take advantage of `Window Functions`.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  c.MemberID, c.fname, c.TaskMstID, c.OnDate, c.Description
FROM
    (
        SELECT  a.MemberID, a.fname,
                b.TaskMstID, b.OnDate, b.Description,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY a.MemberID ORDER BY b.OnDate DESC) RN
        FROM    MemberMst a
                LEFT JOIN TaskMst b
                    ON a.MemberID = b.MemberID
    ) c
WHERE c.RN = 1
```

Comment: sorry to say @John but this doesn't work...!Error:The column 'MemberID' was specified multiple times for 'a'.

Comment: @SHEKHAR SHETE ,In that case specify the column names explicitly

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE you need to explicitly specify the column names in the subquery. i'll just update my answer.

Comment: Hey @JohnWoo! it works fine...! Exactly as i needed..! Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
;With Cte1  AS
(

SELECT  top 5 dbo.MemberMst.MemberID, dbo.MemberMst.fname, dbo.TaskMst.TaskMstID, dbo.TaskMst.OnDate, dbo.TaskMst.Description
FROM   dbo.MemberMst left JOIN
dbo.TaskMst ON dbo.MemberMst.MemberID = dbo.TaskMst.MemberID
),
Cte2 As
(   SELECT Rn = Row_Number() Over(Partition by MemberId Order By OnDate Desc), *
    From Cte1

)
Select * 
From Cte2 
Where Rn = 1
```

Should do the task for you. Try it out.

Comment: You should not get error..These are common table expression being introduce from Sql Server 2005.B/t, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error:Incorrect syntax near 'Cte2'. i am new to his plz explain this type of syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You Just have to USE [Group BY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) Clause with MAX() Function

```
with CTE as(
    SELECT TOP 5 
        dbo.MemberMst.MemberID, 
        dbo.MemberMst.fname, 
        dbo.TaskMst.TaskMstID, 
        dbo.TaskMst.OnDate, 
        dbo.TaskMst.Description
    FROM
        dbo.MemberMst left 
        JOIN dbo.TaskMst 
        ON dbo.MemberMst.MemberID = dbo.TaskMst.MemberID)

select dbo.MemberMst.MemberID, 
        dbo.MemberMst.fname, 
        dbo.TaskMst.TaskMstID, 
        max(dbo.TaskMst.OnDate) as OnDate, 
        dbo.TaskMst.Description
from CTE
group by MemberID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can partition by MemberID, then take a Rank over it and select only the top ranked item.

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Try some thing like this

```
WITH MyCte AS 
(SELECT  top 5 dbo.MemberMst.MemberID, dbo.MemberMst.fname, dbo.TaskMst.TaskMstID, dbo.TaskMst.OnDate, dbo.TaskMst.Description,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.MemberMst.MemberID ORDER BY dbo.TaskMst.OnDate DESC) AS RowNum 
FROM   dbo.MemberMst 
left JOIN dbo.TaskMst ON dbo.MemberMst.MemberID = dbo.TaskMst.MemberID)
SELECT  *
FROM    MyCte
WHERE   RowNum > 0
```

UPDATE:
Changed to ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK() to avoid the problem of multiple rows with same rank.